# The files in a folder are stored in an _nXm_ matrix, where n gives the number of rows and m gives the number of columns

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

In a interview I was asked this 2D matrix problem but not able to think the logic.
Please help me with logic.

> The files in a folder are stored in an *nXm* matrix, where n gives the
>   number of rows and m gives the number of columns.  The numbering
>   system starts from (1,1).
>
> There is a powerful virus in one of the files and the location of the
>   file is given by *(r,c)*.
>
> The virus spreads to adjacent blocks in one second. From each infected
>   block, it takes another second to spread to its adjacent blocks. And
>   so on.
>
> For example, if the virus is at (1,1), it takes a second to spread to
>   the blocks (1,2), (2,1) and (2,2). After two seconds, the infected
>   blocks are  (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (3,2),
>   (3,1).
>
> And so on.
>
> So, given the values of n, m and (r,c), find the number of seconds it
>   will take to spread through the entire folder.
>
> Input Format
>
> The input contains:
>
> The first line contains t test cases.
>
> Each test case contains two lines:
>
> The first line contains n and m separated by a space. Next line of the
>   test case contains (r,c) which gives the position of the virus
>   infected file in the folder. Output Format
>
> The output contains t lines each of which contains the time needed for
>   the virus to spread to the entire folder in minutes and seconds.  Note
>   that if the time taken is less than a minute, the output should be x
>   seconds. If the time is 1 second, the output should be 1 second.  If
>   the time is 1 minute, then the time should be output as 1 minute 0
>   seconds. See the test cases for clarity.
>
> Sample Input
>
> 3
>
> 6 5
>
> (2,2)
>
> 100 50
>
> (39,5)
>
> 44 130
>
> (1,1)
>
> Sample Output
>
> 4 seconds
>
> 1 minute 1 second
>
> 2 minutes
>
> 9 seconds
>
> Explanation
>
> For the first test case, there are 6 rows and 5 columns.  The virus is
>   at position (2,2) it will take 1 second to spread to (1,1), (1,2),
>   (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3).  From there it will take 1
>   more second to spread to adjacent files. To spread to all the files,
>   it will take total of 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just an idea** (need to be proven).

```
n - row count
m - column count

r - row index of virus starting pos.
c - column index of virus starting pos.
```

then answer will be `Math.max(n - r, m - c);`

**Test cases:**

1. Math.max(6 - 2, 5 - 2) == 4 seconds;
2. Math.max(100 - 39, 50 - 5) == 61 seconds == 1 minute 1 second;
3. Math.max(44 - 1, 130 - 1) == 129 seconds == 2 minutes 9 seconds;

**Explanation:**

Let's simplify and suppose we have just one row [1; 100] and the virus starts spreading from 1, then in 99 seconds all cells would be infested.

If the virus starts from 50, then in 50 seconds infestation would be completed.

So we have the following formula `rowSize - (startPos * 2) + startPos <=> rowSize - startPos`

Comment: This wont work for 4,2 virus location in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 2 dimentional array (m, n) of boolean values, initiating everything as false. E.g. `true` means infected, `false` means not infected.

Also, start by making `true` the first infected cell at (r,c).

And then start a loop with the condition "while there are still cells not-infected (false)".

Inside this loop, make a loop through all the cells of the table: for every `infected` cell you should find the adjacent not-infected (false) cells (over, right, left, under) - if they exist, and keep them in a list.

The big loop will end when all the cells are infected. For every iteration in the loop, add 1 to a `seconds` variable. This `seconds` variable at the end will be the number of seconds needed for the full infection of the entire folder.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
table initialization (m,n)
set first infected cell (c,r)
number of seconds = 0
while (not all cells infected) {
    reset the infectionExtensionList
    for (i: columns) {
        for (j: rows) {
            if (i,j is infected) {
                append to the infectionExtensionList: (i+1,j), (i-1,j), (i,j+1), (i,j-1) // if they exist!
            }
        }
    }
    turn all the cells of the infectionExtensionList to infected
    number of seconds ++
}
return number of seconds
```

Good luck!